# Cocoa app crashes when trying to open a save dialog: Timeout occured while waiting for the window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nssavepanel

I wrote an HTML5 app and I'm making a wrapper for it in Cocoa for the Mac. I'm in the process of writing a method that will take a url and let the user save it to their disk. Here is the method so far:

```
- (void) downloadFile: (NSString *) url {

    NSSavePanel * savePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
    [savePanel setAllowedFileTypes: @[@"png"]];
    [savePanel setNameFieldStringValue:@"test"];
    [savePanel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
        //NSArray * files = [[openDlg URLs] valueForKey: @"relativePath"];
        //[resultListener chooseFilenames: files]  ;
    }];
    [savePanel runModal];

}
```

However when I invoke the method (long after the window is made) my app crashes and I get this error in the console: 2013-07-21 18:23:05.067 Reditr[31458:d11f] RVS:__54-[NSRemoteSavePanel _runOrderingOperationWithContext:]_block_invoke_0319 : Timeout occured while waiting for the window

Comment: Have you ever used NSSavePanel?  Maybe, you are trying something new with beginWithCompletionHandler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use both `-runModal` and `-beginWithCompletionHandler:`. Use one or the other (preferably the latter).

Comment: If I don't call [savePanel runModal]; then my app no longer crashes, but I still get the message about a timeout having occurred.